# Как приблизить точку при клике. Yandex Map Api

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Пробую повесить событие клика на точки:

```
geoObjects.addEvents('click', function (e) {
  var placemark = e.get('target'); 

  myMap.panTo([placemark.geometry.getCoordinates()], {
    delay: 0,
    flying: true,
    callback: function () {
    myMap.setZoom(15);
    }
  });

});
```

Но работает только перемещение, `callback` вообще ни в какую не срабатывает. Даже `alert`, хотя делаю по документации, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Решил так:

```
myMap.panTo([placemark.geometry.getCoordinates()], {
                            delay: 0,
                            flying: true
                        }).then(function() {
                            myMap.setZoom(15);
                        });
```